# Grant DBA role to a user in cloud

Tags: cloud, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, informatica-powercenter, sysdba

I logged in as admin and issued grant statement to another user

Grant dba to user;

I got the error DBA role does not exist or the role was not granted. I require this since I am trying to import a table from my local database to cloud database.

I am not a DBA ; self learner so seeking for some help

Thanks

Comment: are u using an anonymous cloud oracle database ??

Comment: Which cloud, what service?